# Sending data from View to another Controller using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to send data from view to another controller using JQuery

```
var title;
var price;
var container;
$('a.btn').click(function () {
    container = $(this).closest('.item');
    title = container.find('.item-dtls > h4 > a').text();
    price = container.find('.price').text(); 
});

$('a.btn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@(Url.Action("Item", "Home"))',
        type:'POST',
        datatype:text,
        data:{title,price},
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

This is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Item(string title,string price) {
    Response.Write(title);
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is your question or your error? To post to another controller; create controller and an action. Use those in the `@Url.` statement.

Comment: i want get title and price of object that clicked and send title and price to another controller

Answer (score 2):

Send the data as name-value pairs. Also you do not need two separate click event handlers.

Also, the `datatype` property value should be a string. so wrap that in single/double quotes.

```
$('a.btn').click(function () {
     var container = $(this).closest('.item');

     var titleVal = container.find('.item-dtls > h4 > a').text();
     var priceVal = container.find('.price').text(); 

     alert(titleVal);
     alert(priceVal);
     $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("Item", "Home")',
         type:'POST',
         datatype:'text',
         data: { title : titleVal , price : priceVal },
         success: function (data) {
             alert('success');
             alert(data);
         },
         error: function (data) {
             alert('error'); }
         });
     });

});
```

Also, You cannot use `Response.Write` to return something from your action method. You can use `Content` method to return a string.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Item(string title, string price)
{        
    return Content(title);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any script errors ? Are you sure you  are able to read the values from your DOM for `titleVal` and `priceVal` variables ?

Comment: but the error method just runing and alert('error')

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer. You need to fix your action method.

Comment: I tried the exact code in the answer with hard coded values for the two variables and it worked for me. So I guess you have some other script error in your page. Check your browser console.

Comment: now i want return view in Item method how do this?when i try return view(); not work

Comment: `return View();` should work as long as you have a view called`Item.cshtml ` in `~/Views/Home` or ~/Views/Shared` location. Also it is not a good idea to ask a totally different question in comments. :)